Is it possible to compose attribute-selector components transparently?
I am using a component library in Angular. They provide a button component with the selector button[extButton], since we usually don't want to wrap buttons in another custom tag and having to proxy the various actions.
However, I want to have my own button components, let's say with the selector button[appButton]. Is there any way to apply both components, but just using <button appButton> in the temples. I don't want to reference the attribute from the library directly in case we decide to change the library or implementation of the button.
Is this possible?
I've tried extending the component, and using host.[extButton] = 'something' in the decorator to pass some necessary attribute values but it doesn't seem to be working.

You should extends the Directive. I imagine some like
@Directive({
   selector: 'button[appButton]'
})
export class AppButtonDirective extends ExButtonDirective{
  constructor(){
      super()
  }
 }

See that both constructor should to have the same arguments (and pass to super these arguments)

Does it make a difference if they are both components, not directives? Since the external button is a Component, not a directive.

You can not "extends" a component (well, you can, but don't sare the .html). A Directive can "improve" a component (give more properties and behaivour) and you can create a component that add a component in its view, but adding a tag using javascript not create a component.
